# ¿Por qué este código javascript es invalido?. ¿Value es una palabra reservada?

Tags: javascript, variables

```js
var value = 0;
if(value===0){
    return true; 
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

La respuesta a este código es:

> Invalid JavaScrip

¿Cual es el motivo?

Answer (score 10):

Los returns solo pueden ser llamados en funciones.

```js
var value = 0;

function comprobar(valor){
  if(value===0){
      return true; 
  }
  else{
      return false;
  }
}

console.log(comprobar(value));
```